# Git diff including multiple unrelated repositories

Tags: git

I have two unrelated repositories, each of which has some change that has been added but not committed. Individually, the correct diff output is seen via `git diff --cached`.

I would like to know if there is some usage of `git diff` that will allow me to essentially concatenate `git diff --cached` from both repositories (for example, in `path-a` and `path-b`). I desire this because our review tool only accepts flags passed to a single `git diff` and does not support multiple calls, so something like `git diff ... && git diff ...` is not possible.

Comment: It seems I can't add `git-diff` as a tag?

Comment: [tag:git-diff] is a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) for [tag:git].

Comment: Output both diffs to a file, then concatenate them together with `cat`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to do that. The review tool issues the call to git, not me; and I can't modify the review tool to issue two git calls and then a cat.

Answer (score 1):

Under linux all calls to `git <something>` is actually a call to `git-<something>` so it's easy to add new commands. Gerrit for example adds `git review` this way.

The commands are simple shell-scripts so perhaps you can add `git customdiff` to your review engines machine.